# Update Parent entity and add new child entities in EF Core Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have below classes

```
public class Parent 
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<Child> Children {get;set;}      
}

public class Child
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string AnotherProp {get;set;}
  public int ParentId {get;set;}
}
```

Now my Parent entity has one row and it has 2 child rows.

From api, I got an update for that particular parent row as well as insert new child row (note: after inserting new one there will be 3 children). I am doing below to add new child to the parent.

```
 existingParent.Children.Add(newChild);
 context.Parents.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I am getting the exception :
Exception: DbUpdateConcurrencyException, ExceptionMessage: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.  Please advice.

Comment: Where is Update code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781548/database-operation-expected-to-affect-1-rows-but-actually-affected-0-rows)

Comment: What's the content of `newChild`? And which insert/update statements are executed?